# Help with a proof for the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$

Tags: integers, irrational-numbers

The following proof comes from Ian Stewart's *Galois Theory*.

Assume for a contradiction that there exists integers $a$, $b$ with $b\neq0$ such that $(\frac{a}{b})^2=2$.

1. We may assume that $a, b>0$.
2. Observe that if such an expression exists, then there must be one in which $b$ is as small as possible.
3. Show that $(\frac{2b-a}{a-b})^2=2$.
4. Show that $2b-a>0$, $a-b>0$.
5. Show that $a-b<b$, a contradiction.

I do not follow step 4 & 5. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Can you think of any bounds for $a/b$?

Comment: Title: why do you think the proof is "new" or "novel"? I also suppose it has been explained here already, perhaps [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853422/proof-of-the-irrationality-of-sqrt2?rq=1).

Comment: $a-b<b$ follows directly from $2b-a > 0$. Did you even tried?

Comment: @DietrichBurde You are correct-the wording was indeed presumptive. And I skimmed through the post you mentioned too hastily and completely missed the answer. I shall flag the post.

Comment: @Alexander51413 I appreciate the hint!

Comment: @jjagmathI did; but what I failed to follow is "a contradiction" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 1 and 2 it's already assumed that $a,b$ is a pair of positive integers that satisfy $\displaystyle \left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^2=2$, and among all the possible pairs of $(a,b)$, this pair is where $b$ is the smallest. In other words, any smaller pair with a smaller $b$ would lead to contradiction. That's what is explained in step 4 and 5.

Comment: Thank you very much! Apparently this question already had a answer from a different post (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2853422/506332), hence I have flagged it.